# How to hide what blocks an item can break

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

there is a command which gives you a Pickaxe that can only break a certain block.
if there is a way then how do you make it so it doesn't say which block that is. 
version:1.14.4

Answer (score 2):

You can hide any specific combination of data about any tool or block by using the {HideFlags:VALUE} tag. In your case, you specifically want {HideFlags:8}. As the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags) says:

> {HideFlags:VALUE} - VALUE ranges from 1 to 63, representing 63 combinations.
>
> When adding to create a unique VALUE,
> Adding 1 will hide Enchantments
> Adding 2 will hide Attributes modifiers
> Adding 4 will hide Unbreakable
> Adding 8 will hide CanDestroy
> Adding 16 will hide CanPlaceOn
> Adding 32 will hide Others, such as potion effects & shield pattern info
>
> In binary form:
>
> [+32] [+16] [+8] [+4] [+2] [+1]
>
> For example: "000111" has a value of 7, and it will hide Enchantments, Attribute Modifiers, and Unbreakable.